# Context Default Value is Null in Child Job

Tags: talend

I have 2 Jobs - **Job 1 and Job2** and Global Context Variables with default values in Talend both the Job's use the same context variables but when I run the **Job2** from **Job1** instead of having the default variables the Global Context Variables has NULL Value

This only happens when I run **Job2** from **Job1** if I run the **Job2** Separately it runs correctly

Please anyone point me what is wrong in the flow

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for context values to be transmitted from parent to child job, you must activate the option "Transmit whole context" on the tRunJob component which runs the child job.